# Play iPhone camera shutter sound when I click a button

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, avfoundation

How do I play the shutter sound from iPhone when I click a button?

Answer (score 17):

You can use `AudioToolbox` and pure magical number `1108` like this:

Swift:

```
import AudioToolbox
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1108)
```

Objective-C:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1108);
```

Here is [full list of these pure magical ids](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: there's no define or a constant for that by any chance?

Comment: As far as I know there is no constant for it. Here is full list: https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 7):

1) Search online for a camera shutter wave file. You can trim this one if it is a bit long using a .wav editor
http://www.freesound.org/people/Nathan_Lomeli/sounds/79190/

2) Name it shutter.wav and put it into your development directory along with your other resources.

3) Define the sound in your view's .h file

```
@interface  myViewController : UIViewController {
    SystemSoundID SoundID;
}
```

4) Load the file in your View's "viewDidLoad" event:

```
  //load a sound wav file to use for the shutter
NSURL *buttonURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"shutter" ofType:@"wav"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)buttonURL, &SoundID);
```

5) In your button_click event:

```
   //play then shutter.wav sound
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
```

Comment: download from here : http://www.freesound.org/data/previews/79/79190_1231186-lq.mp3

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify a programming language, but let's assume ObjC for now and not Monotouch or any other 3rd party framework.

AVAudioPlayer from the AV framework is your friend.

Please see the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAudioPlayer) here at Apple

Or do a search on AVAudioPlayer here on SO and you will find dozens of examples.
Still, you will have to grab the shutter sound file from somewhere but you can take any public available shutter WAV you find on Google.

If you really want to use the camera, the shutter sound will be played automatically when a picture is taken but I doubt that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, yea its ObjC .. Sorry I forgot that .. Okej, so I have to add my WAV file myself. Thought there was a way to use the System file..

Answer (score 0):

some sounds to pick to those location : /System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds
/System/Library/Sounds

Comment: user282070: Isn't the sound copyrighted? can you use the sounds in the folder for a commercial product?